# rxjava2 not call onSuccess after interval and toList

Tags: rx-java2

Here is a sample Code I used:

```
Observable.interval(0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Long>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Long> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(aLong);
                    list.add(aLong);
                    list.add(aLong);
                    list.add(aLong);
                    return Observable.fromIterable(list);
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<Long>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Long>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Long> longs) {
                    Log.e("test", "onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("test", "onError");
                }
            });
```

I'm a newbie to rxjava2, I don't why the onSuccess or onError not be called in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have an source Observable (`interval()`) that emit infinite number of items, and nothings stops it down the stream.
`toList()` have to wait to `onComplete()` in order to know when the stream stops and collects all the items it emitted to a list.
In other words, as your'e Observable has infinite items, you can't collect it to List as it is finite collection.  The observable will do nothing as it will waits forever for all the items.